# Apply filter on $geoWithin MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, gis

I'm storing all Points, Linestrings and Polygons in a collection. I can retrieve all the Points and Linestring within a given polygon using $geoWithin as shown:

```
db.BLR_all.find(
   {
       "geom" : {
          "$geoWithin" : {
              "$geometry" : {
                    "type" : "Polygon",
                    "coordinates" : [ [ /** array of points **/ ] ] 
                }
            }
        }
    })
```

How can I modify the above query to extract only the Point types in the given polygon?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your query modification is actually quite simple, just include the filter condition for the GeoJSON type in the query:

```js
db.BLR_all.find(
   {
       "geom" : {
          "$geoWithin" : {
              "$geometry" : {
                    "type" : "Polygon",
                    "coordinates" : [ [ /** array of points **/ ] ] 
                }
            }
        },
        "geom.type": "Point"
    })
```

Or specifically over some sample data,

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("534cb37acca5f311cc5c23cc"),
    "loc" : {
            "type" : "Polygon",
            "coordinates" : [
                    [
                            [
                                    0,
                                    0
                            ],
                            [
                                    3,
                                    6
                            ],
                            [
                                    6,
                                    1
                            ],
                            [
                                    0,
                                    0
                            ]
                    ]
            ]
    }
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("535aeddfb6b8fd04b3424a09"),
    "loc" : {
            "type" : "Point",
            "coordinates" : [
                    3,
                    6
            ]
    }
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("535aef22b6b8fd04b3424a0a"),
    "loc" : {
            "type" : "Point",
            "coordinates" : [
                    9,
                    12
            ]
    }
}
```

Issuing a query:

```js
db.geo.find({ 
    "loc": { 
        "$geoWithin": { 
            "$geometry": { 
                "type": "Polygon", 
                "coordinates":  [ [ [ 0, 0 ], [ 3, 6 ], [ 6, 1 ], [ 0, 0 ] ] ] 
            } 
        }
    }, 
    "loc.type": "Point" 
})
```

Will only return items that are a "Point" and within the coordinates bounds.

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("535aeddfb6b8fd04b3424a09"),
    "loc" : {
            "type" : "Point",
            "coordinates" : [
                    3,
                    6
            ]
    }
}
```